# Flask-Security register user while already logged in as admin

Tags: python, flask, flask-security

So I've got a simple web app which allows the admin to create accounts for users (this procedure is necessary like this). Therefore, I have a user management page where the admin account is able to add new users to the system. I've managed to add the WTForms/Flask-Security form to a simple modal:

```
<div class="modal-content m-b-20">
  <h4>add new user</h4>
  <form action="{{ url_for_security('register') }}" method="POST" name="register_user_form">
    {{ register_user_form.hidden_tag() }}
    {{ render_field_with_errors(register_user_form.email) }}
    {{ render_field_with_errors(register_user_form.password) }}
    {% if register_user_form.password_confirm %}
      {{ render_field_with_errors(register_user_form.password_confirm) }}
    {% endif %}
    {{ render_field(register_user_form.submit) }}
  </form>
</div>
```

When I enter a new username and a password I am just redirected to `/`. I can see in the network tab of Firefox web dev tools that the `POST` request gets an `302 FOUND` response.

As flask-security takes care of the database requests (I use sqlite) during the login procedure I expected it to also add them automatically to the database for registering. However, after registering no entries have been added. I tried *catching* the `POST` request manually but somehow the following code is never invoked, even though the form `action` is targeted at `/register`.

```
@APP.route('/register', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
@roles_required('admin')
def register():
    print('asdf')
```

I've no idea how to further debug this or what I am doing wrong. Maybe this is an issue because I am trying to register an account as an already logged-in user?

EDIT: Ok, after completely disabling the `login_required`s I am now able to register users over my WTForms modal. This means that the main problem seems to be the fact that I am already logged in as the admin user. Does anybody know how to enable the registration as a logged-in user?